# Makefile for multiple files in different directories

Tags: c, makefile

I am a newbie in creating makefiles, and would be glad if someone could help me.

I have created several header files (for function declarations) and corresponding .c programs (8 in total), for the function definitions (including the main function). These are listed in the ***.../include/*** directory. Additionally, I have created another directory for the storing the output files : **.../bin/** after compilation. I tried to link the .o files, but was unsuccessful. I have attached a small piece of the makefile code (similar one taken from the internet) :

```
CC  =   g++
CFLAGS  = -Wall -O3 
INC_DIR :=  /media/sf_~share/151*/Codes/include
OBJ_DIR :=  /media/sf_~share/151*/Codes/obj
INC_FILES   :=  $(wildcard $(INC_DIR)/%.c)
OBJ_FILES   :=  $(patsubst $(INC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(INC_FILES))

all : $(APP)
$(APP)  : $(OBJ_FILES)
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o  : $(INC_DIR)/%.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
  rm -f *.o $(APP)
```

I would be glad if someone could either suggest me a different code, or rectify this as it is.

Comment: Is there an error? Why do you say it didn't work?

Comment: What do you expect from `/media/sf_~share/151*/Codes/include`? I mean, how do you think the `~` and `*` character will be interpreted by make?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your Makefile:

**Wildcard usage**

You should use `*.c` rather than `%.c` for [wildcard expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html), like this:

```
INC_FILES   :=  $(wildcard $(INC_DIR)/*.c)
```

**Patsubst usage**

You don't need to specify the full pattern `$(INC_DIR)/%.c` for `patsubst`, instead, simply use:

```
OBJ_FILES   :=  $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(INC_FILES))
```

**Missing $(APP) value**

I don't know if you simply forgot to add this to the sample or not, but since `$(APP)` is an empty string, the makefile says:

> make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Adding `APP := program` triggers a build for all the `*.c` files in `include`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added this line :

Comment: @sthavishthabhopalam, sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Did this fix your issue?

Comment: APP := conv_error error_compute .... (list of all .c files, without .c in the end). I tried using the commands : make app/make all/make . But I seem to be getting the error : ***.empty variable name. Stop.

Comment: @sthavishthabhopalam, `app` should contain **ONLY** the name of the output executable!

Comment: all my files with '.c' extension (7 .c files and 1 main.c) when compiled will generate '.o' executable files for each '.c'. Are you mentioning that I need to mention only one '.c' file - that is the main ?

Comment: @sthavishthabhopalam, you should select a name for your executable and then write `APP := <desired-name-of-executable>`

Comment: Thanks for that. I renamed the executable as `executable` itself. However, I seem to get this error now : `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'execute' failed
make: *** [execute] Error 1
`